# Branch is up to date but pulling origin still results in changes

Tags: git

If I checkout my development branch and do `git status` I get the message:

`Switched to branch development
Your branch is up to date with origin/development`

But when I do `git pull origin development` it still pulls down new changes.

Why new changes were pulled even when the branch was up to date?

Comment: The first message compares development against what origin/development looked like the last time git talked to your remote. The remote might have more changes that you don't have locally. Pull will automatically do a fetch, which will bring those changes down into your local clone, and thus update origin/development. And then merge. If you want to make sure you are comparing the right things, do a `git fetch` first.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen ok, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your branch is up to date with origin/development

This statement cannot be trusted always.

The`git status` just compares your local copy branch with your corresponding local remote-tracking branch and not with the original remote branch which resides on the server.

Although local remote-tracking branches are supposed to match the status of the original remote branch on the server they are bound with some limitations.

The remote-tracking branches are moved forward only when network-related commands are used.

For Ex:

Let's say this is the current status of the original remote branch on the server.

```
   master
     |
A <- B
```

And this is the status of the local working branch and the local remote-tracking which tracks the original master branch on the server.

```
 remote/master
      |
 A <- B
      |
    master
```

Now let's say, you do some new work and commit that work without pushing it to sever, so this is what your status would look like

Server master

```
   master
     |
A <- B
```

Local master and Local remote/master

```
 remote/master
      |
 A <- B <- C
           |
        master
```

If you run `git status` now, git will respond by showing that you are 1 commit ahead of the master as it just compares your local master branch with your local remote/master tracking branch and not with the original master branch on the server. Luckily the status of the remote/master and the server master in this scenario is exactly the same but this is not always the case.

Assume this scenario, where one other fellow developer is also pushing things to same original master branch on the server.

So after these two new pushes from another developer your original master branch on the server would look like this,

Server master

```
             master
               |
A <- B <- D <- E
```

And you're local master branch and local remote/master branch will still have the same status as if nothing ever happened.

```
 remote/master
      |
 A <- B <- C
           |
        master
```

The remote/master branch shows no movement at all. This happens because remote/master is only moved forward by git when any network communication-related commands are executed from your local machine. Since no network call was made from your machine the petty remote/master had no chance to fetch the status of the remote server master branch and then change its status. The dumb remote/master still thinks that it is up to date with the status of the original remote server master branch.

If you run `git status` now, `git` will still respond by showing that you are just 1 commit ahead of the master, which as we know is not the case.

This is what happened in your case,

When you fired `git status`, git replied

> Your branch is up to date with origin/development

because it just compared your local development branch with the local remote/development branch, but in the meanwhile, someone had already pushed some changes to the server original development branch and hence when you do `git pull` it brings you those changes from server and merges them in your local branch.

Answer (score 0):

The up to date can be misleading, it's up to date in only one way i.e. you don't have new changes on your local repository since the last time you fetch origin.

If you commit some changes and do a `git status` you will see that you have one commit in advance from origin.

If you want to know if origin has new changes compared to your local repository you can use `git fetch` ans then `git status` will tell you that there are some changes on origin